Need driver software for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on an Asus UX564 (Zenbook Flip)
Could you help me recommend which additional (preferably proprietary) drivers (in form of programs and packages) I should install to get Linux perfectly stable and all features to run on my Asus Zenbook UX564PH? It has an Asus Pen I'd love to be able to use with it. I can also flip the notebook 180° to act as a tablet. Are there ways to disable the keyboard and touchpad when flipped?
Could you help me what to set in Grub, firmware wise, drivers, etc?
Should I install tools like laptop-mode-tools ?
My GPU is Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 Max-Q
Here is some hardware info https://imgur.com/a/7rQRqIc
The general manual is here https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/UX564PH/0409_E17801_UX564EH_EI_V2_A.pdf?model=UX564PH
I already thought about installing
pulseaudio + pulseeffects to replace the GUI Realtek audio console
gnome-color-manager for the GUI Intel graphic control center
Thanks in advance!

general approach for this: find manufacturer and device id (lspci, lsusb depending on how it is connected) and then search online for these 2 icm, driver and linux.  BUT as long as the device is connected during install the system installs and activates a driver, If it does not it is likely unsupported. "pulseaudio" forget about that. "pipewire" is the new sound system. and forget about "laptop-mode-tools" those tools are incorporated in the kernel.
